# Lazy loading images in Tkinter Python

Tags: python, image, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to make a windows style image viewer that can display multiple images at once in an icon or thumbnail format (like when you do View > Layout > Large Icons on windows) in tkinter. However, the folder I want to open contains a couple of hundred images and it's way to slow to load them all and will probably use too much memory anyway. Therefore I'm trying to lazy load images based on if they are visible (i.e: if the user has scrolled down enough to see it). Here's what I have so far:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk
import glob
import datetime
import os

class ImageListViewer(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root, img_paths, *args, **kwargs):        
        self.img_paths = img_paths
        self.root = root
        self.canvas = Canvas(root)
        self.scroll_y = Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.frame = Frame(self.canvas, bg='red')

        self.max_w, self.max_h = 200, 200
        cols = 3

        loading_img = Image.open('loading.png')
        loading_img = self.fit_img(loading_img, self.max_w, self.max_h)
        loading_photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(loading_img)

        # group of widgets
        for i, path in enumerate(img_paths):
            label = Label(self.frame, image=loading_photo, width=self.max_w, height=self.max_h, borderwidth=2, relief="sunken")
            label.photo = loading_photo
            # label = Label(self.frame, text=str(i), width=self.max_w, height=self.max_h, borderwidth=2, relief="sunken")
            label.index = i
            label.has_img = False
            label.grid(row=i-i%cols, column=i%cols)

        self.canvas.create_window(0, 0, anchor='nw', window=self.frame)
        self.canvas.update_idletasks()

        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox('all'), 
                              yscrollcommand=self.scroll_intercepter)

        self.canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True, side='left')
        self.scroll_y.pack(fill='y', side='right')

        self.root.bind('h', self.debug)

        super().__init__(root)

    def scroll_intercepter(self, a, b):
        for label in self.labels_in_view():
            if not label.has_img:
                self.lazy_load_img(label)
        self.scroll_y.set(a, b)

    def lazy_load_img(self, label):
        img = Image.open(self.img_paths[label.index])
        img = self.fit_img(img, self.max_w, self.max_h)
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        label.config(image = photo)
        label.photo = photo
        # label.config(bg = 'red')
        label.has_img = True

    def labels_in_view(self, show=False):
        if show:
            print('Root:', self.root.winfo_width(), self.root.winfo_height())
        for label in self.frame.winfo_children():
            label_x = label.winfo_rootx() #- label.winfo_width()
            label_y = label.winfo_rooty() #- label.winfo_height()
            if show:
                print(label.index, label_x, label_y)
            x_in = 0 <= label_x < self.root.winfo_width() 
            y_in = 0 <= label_y < self.root.winfo_height()
            if x_in and y_in:
                yield label

    def debug(self, event):
        print([l.index for l in self.labels_in_view(show=True)], '\n')

    @staticmethod
    def fit_img(img, width, height, keep_aspect=True):
        if keep_aspect:
            w, h = img.size
            ratio = min(width/w, height/h)
            image = img.resize((int(w*ratio), int(h*ratio)))
        else:
            image = img.resize((width, height))
        return image

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Image List Viewer")
    root.geometry('400x400')
    paths = glob.glob('*.JPG')
    ImageListViewer(root, paths).pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

The labels_in_view method tries to only return labels (which contain the images) that are displayed. Each label is originally loaded with a dummy 'loading' image. You can also see I've binded 'h' to display some extra debugging info.

Here's the problem, past tens of images it completely hangs. If one were to scroll to the end of all the images, it tries to load all the intermediate images from top to bottom and not only the ones that are viewable.

This is certainly because of how I intercept the scrollbar call back to then lazy load but I cannot figure out any other way of doing it. Is there a better way? Maybe a better library too, tkinter is rather slow although I'd rather not restart from scratch?

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

EDIT: Images should only be loaded once because of the label.has_img flag that is set to true once the image has been loaded.

Comment: Are you sure you are not constantly reloading the images once they are in view?

Comment: They shouldn't be because of the label.has_img flag. Please see the edit above.

Comment: I don't think the `labels_in_view()` method would work correctly, so you might want to verify that it does what is needed. Regardless, it seems like this approach could potentially (eventually) load all the images into memory if the user scrolls through the entire list since there's nothing unloading the images which are no longer visible.

Comment: You are correct, I'm not unloading images and I should. I figured, however, that to start I could get the loading part working first!

Comment: Did you ever check to see whether the `labels_in_view()` method works?

Comment: Yes, I did. It's not perfect (they are "in view" slightly after they come on screen, they need to be half on screen) but it should be enough.